# parallel programming using Visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, sorting, visual-studio-2017, openmp

```
int partition(int arr[], int l, int h)
{
    int x = arr[h];
    int i = (l - 1);
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int j = l; j <= h - 1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] <= x)
        {
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[h]);
    return (i + 1);
}
```

I try to use OpenMP on iterative quick sort program.
The code above is the partition part which use last element in arr[] as pivot
and i suppose in quick sort, xxx pivot yyy as i increase from leftmost to pivot, it does not matter which number swap first, those number is smaller than pivot

but the answer produced is not a sorted array.(sorted partially)
After that, i guess it is caused by race condition on "i++"
i tested i(printf i after/before swap), i is consecutive(wrong order, but doesnt matter?) that should means values from leftmost to pivot position have changed, no race condition.

also i tried add

```
#pragma omp atomic
```

before the i++, but it seems no different after change.
I use parallel on this loop only. And i dont know which part of code cause the disordered sorting.

Answer (score 1):

1. For the parallel algorithm to work, the individual iterations of the for loop should be generally independent. In this case, the individual iterations are not independent.
2. The race condition can happen not only in i++ part, but also on the swapping part.

Comment: Suppose race condition does not happen on i. swap arr of corresponding i with j should not affect the answer, eg. 0->x is smaller than pivot. i is consecutive for each iteration. That means swap 0->x with corresponding arr[j]. Since arr[0->x] is smaller than pivot. it should not affect the further operation?

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on using OpenMP in this function?